# How do I disable the titlepage when generating a PDF via DocBook and FOP?

Tags: apache-fop, docbook

Not that it is all that entirely practicle, I have a particular customer that is wanting to turn off the title pages in their PDFs that are getting generated. I looked and looked through the DocBook FOP parameters and documentation and couldn't find a way to disable the titlepage. I found ways to customize however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the document type from a book to an article. This removed the title page and everything else not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a PDF filter and strip away the first page?

Comment: Though this method will probably not fix page numbers. The title page starts at `i`.

Answer (score 1):

I've just started looking into docbook and this is also what I'm trying to do at the moment. As far as I've read it is suggested to create a custom titlepage xsl (which could be genereted from your own titlepage.xml file - sample could be found under docbook-xsl-ns-1.76.1\template)

It's explained here : http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/HTMLTitlePage.html

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to add this to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template name="book.titlepage.recto"/>
<xsl:template name="book.titlepage.before.verso"/>
```